# Sybase SQL Anywhere: Does LOAD TABLE function works within a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, sybase, sqlanywhere

I can run successfully the following code outside a stored procedure:

```
LOAD TABLE myTable(col1, col2, col3)
USING CLIENT FILE 'path_to_my_file'
ESCAPES OFF
SKIP 1
DEFAULTS ON
MESSAGE LOG '/path_to_my_file/m.log'
ROW LOG '/path_to_my_file/r.log' 
ONLY LOG UNIQUE;
```

But when I try to set it inside the sp, I get the following error:

Could not execute statement.

Syntax error near 'LOAD' on line 4
SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State="42000"
Line 1, column 1

Is there a restriction for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the command in a way it was not designed to do. I suggest creating a script file and call that script file externally.

"Using command files to load data

To load large amounts of data, most users create command files. To create a command file, follow the instructions in Chapter 2, “Using Interactive SQL (dbisql),”in the Utility Guide."

from

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1510/html/iqapgv1/X100956.htm